# Appsync Filtering list on @connection

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, vtl

I have a schema as such

```
type District @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    workers: [Worker] @connection(name: "DistrictWorker")
}
type Service @model{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    workers: [Worker] @connection(name: "ServiceWorker")
}
type Worker @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    service: Service @connection(name: "ServiceWorker")
    district: District @connection(name: "DistrictWorker")
}
```

I want to query at ***Worker*** applying ***Service*** and/or ***District*** filter over the connection.
I guess i have to write some custom resolver maybe pipelined resolver, I want some guidence on how could i achieve it.

Are there any different approach for achieving the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can filter their queries over the connection by adding the desired filter field to their respective `ModelFilterInput`'s. Amplify with Appsync does a great job by generating the resolver and wiring them up to their specific tables just from the schema we define. I, wonder why the generated `ModelFilterInput`'s for the tables don't include the connection field.

For the schema above defined i have modified the generated code as follows:

```
input ModelWorkerFilterInput {
    id: ModelIDFilterInput
    name: ModelStringFilterInput
    source: ModelStringFilterInput
    phone: ModelStringFilterInput
    workerServiceId: ModelStringFilterInput # added For @connection(name: "ServiceWorker")
    workerDistrictId: ModelStringFilterInput # added For @connection(name: "DistrictWorker") 
    and: [ModelWorkerFilterInput]
    or: [ModelWorkerFilterInput]
    not: ModelWorkerFilterInput
}
```